# Conditional formatting upon another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I want to enter the text in a cell, but its depend upon another cell value formatting.
example:

In A1 value is "Vaibhav" and if I will make it in bold(Ctrl+B), then automatically the next consecutive cell value will come as "Present", else will come as "Absent".

> **vaibhav**     present
>   reena       absent
>   **rahul**   present
>   **vijay**   present
>   nikita          absent

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: yes, but nothing is working.

Comment: Can I suggest simple  VBA method to you?

Comment: What you describe is not "conditional formatting", when you change content of a cell (present / absent) is not formatting! As @RajeshS has mentioned already, it require VBA to implement your desired functionality. However I'd not suggest that. Formatting in Excel is not for storing any information, it's very easy to accidentally loose formatting and so information too. I'd suggest the other way round: enter present/absent in the second column (maybe using data validation drop-down) and apply conditional formatting (bold font) on your first column.

Comment: What is the overall goal you want to accomplish? Are you just looking for a simple way to document attendance? Or does it have to be completed specifically as you suggest?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but as I mentioned that I want to fill the next column with (present/absent), just making the name as "bold", rather than to select that (present/absent) and than names will be reflected as bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, this isn't technically conditional formatting.

To do this you need to do use VBA - so open up the VBA editor (Alt+F11), create a new module (menu option "Insert", then "Module") and put this code into that module:

```vb
Public Function IsBold(ref As Range)
    If ref.Font.FontStyle = "Bold" Then
        IsBold = True
    Else
        IsBold = False
    End If
End Function
```

Close the editor and, assuming that your first name ("vaibhav") is in cell A1, put the following into B1:

```vb
=IF(isbold(A1), "present", "absent")
```

Given that `FontStyle` returns `Bold`, I suspect that this might not work for non-English versions of Excel - however I'm unable to test this.

Comment: Dear Richard, thank you for your answer, it was really a great help for me.